# Parse First N Lines of CSV on Model Save

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models

I have a model where users can upload a CSV, however because the files might sometimes be too big, I'd like to parse the first 5 lines of the uploaded CSV and create a new CSV file. This will act as a sample file, that will be smaller and faster to work with later on.

This is what my `models.py` looks like:

```
from django.db import models

class Source(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    sample = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # I want to parse the 'file' field and write it to 'sample' here


        super(Source, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Basically in the save function of the model, I want to parse the first 5 lines of the `file` field and take those first 5 lines, create a CSV and upload it to the `sample` field`. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import io
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.db import models

class Source(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    sample = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    _generate_sample = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Source, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.file and self._generate_sample:
            with open(self.file.path) as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                lines = [next(reader) for x in xrange(5)]
            output = io.BytesIO()
            writer = csv.writer(output)
            writer.writerows(lines)
            self._generate_sample = False
            self.sample.save('short.csv', ContentFile(output.getvalue()))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```